# Who is the first one suggest the current Continuity equation? Gustav Kirchhoff?

Tags: electromagnetism

Maxwell's equations suggest by Maxwell himself includes the current continuity equation. Continuity equation led the Maxwell to introduce the concept of displacement current that leads the whole Maxwell's equations. Hence, continuity equation is very important. I would like to know the continuity equation can be credit to whom.
I have seen that Gustav Kirchhoff has a paper "On the motion of electricity in conductors" published on 1857. In which the continuity equation has been applied. Is he the first one utilize the continuity equation? If not, who?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it properly belongs to HSM SE.

Comment: I agree, one should move the question. Also, for specification, are you talking about any continuity equation, like in hydrodynamics or elasticity theory, or especially some version of the electrical charge continuity equation?